# -bash: ORACLE_HOME: command not found

Tags: linux, oracle, environment-variables

the following error raise when i login to oracle account on Company Oracle CentOS linux server :

> -bash: ORACLE_HOME: command not found

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

# User specific aliases and functions
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle;export ORACLE_BASE;
ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/10.2.0/db_1;export ORACLE_HOME;
ORACLE_SID=CPS;export ORACLE_SID;
ORACLE_TERM=xterm;export ORACLE_TERM;
PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH;export PATH;
PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH;export PATH;

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib;export LD_LIBRARY_PATH;
CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/JRE:$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib;export CLASSPATH;
```

Comment: This is your `.basrc` file, not a command to log into Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

The exports are bad:

```
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle;export ORACLE_BASE;
```

shoud be:

```
export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
```

and so on.

Comment: and /etc/bashrc? is something in there?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to change exports as @Florin Ghita wrote, source .bashrc:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

and then check

```
echo $ORACLE_HOME
```

to see if the variable is set.

Answer (score 0):

`ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle;export $ORACLE_BASE;`

`ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/10.2.0/db_1;export $ORACLE_HOME;`

`ORACLE_SID=CPS;export $ORACLE_SID;`

and so on .....

also check u opened a new shell before checking if the environment variables are set correctly ..